# Mercurial, file become untracked

Tags: mercurial, nuget

Hi I have a problem with mercurial.
I have a web project in visual studio. And i'm using NuGet. Whenever I update/install new package with NuGet it did something so my web.config file become untracked in mercurial.
So if I run hg status it shows ? web.config

How can I tell mercurial that web.config was just changed? So i can just push changes.

If call hg add web.config and push changes it corrupt my repository.

Comment: Something is wrong outside of Mercurial.  Either some application is editing or deleting files in the `.hg` directory.  You probably need to join #mercurial and go through this step by step.  If you want to try to do this here on SO you'll need to provide the output of `hg status`, `hg summary`, and `hg verify` both begin and after the `hg add`

Comment: Are you also using a Visual Studio plug-in for Mercurial.  Perhaps HgSccPackage or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> If call hg add web.config and push changes it corrupt my repository.

You may have a deeper issue going on.  You need to verify the existing repository soon.  Do the following:

```
hg verify --verbose
```

and report back what it says.